# Paradigmatic sizeHint() from QWidget::createWindowContainer?

Tags: c++, qt

So, I wrapped a custom `QWindow` in a widget using `createWindowContainer`. By default this gives a invalid size hint (-1)  because the QWindow isn't in a layout. Furthermore, `QWindow` doesn't have a size hint.

How can I specify the `sizeHint()` using a function in `render_surface`?

```
window_container = QWidget::createWindowContainer(render_surface);
auto hint = window_container->sizeHint(); // how do I specify this?
std::cout << hint.width() << std::endl;  //invalid
```

Comment: Reported as a "bug" https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-57693

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted something on the bug tracker, the current method is to use a second widget to "shadow" the size.

The code looks something like:

In the parent's constructor

```
auto window_container = QWidget::createWindowContainer(render_surface);
window_container->setLayout(new QGridLayout());
fml = new PlaceHolderWidget;
window_container->layout()->addWidget(fml);
```

In the parent's resize event

```
void RenderContainer::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event)
{
    auto frame_size = render_surface->img_size;
    if (frame_size.n() > 0)
    {
      ...
      fml->setSizeHint(QSize(predicted_width, predicted_height));
    }
    QWidget::resizeEvent(event);
}
```

Where `PlaceHolderWidget` overrides `sizeHint()`.
https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-57693

Comment: Hi, could you please share the entire code you used? I think the part where you define PlaceHolderWidget is missing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Overwrite `virtual const QSize& sizeHint() const` method to the wrapper, method which simply returns [QWindow::size()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwindow.html#size) of its wrapped window.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, `createWindowContainer` returns a QWidget, rather than a custom class of my design.

Comment: Ah, I see, you don't have control over the factory method of the widgets. Can your switch your code to make use of such a method that you are going to write?